# Using the Entry title variable in an Channel Entry field

Tags: channel-entries

I have a Channel Entry field that contains a table. I need the caption to contain the title. I tried:

```
<caption>{title}</caption>
```

Thinking it would work, given that it's within the scope of the Entry, but that didn't work.

What would I need to write?

Comment: You'll need to provide some more details. Is `{title}` within a channel entries loop?

Comment: Hi Jason, I don't mean within the a template. I mean within the Entry editor itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Allow EE code plugin](https://github.com/EllisLab/Allow-Eecode) to... allow EE code within your fields.

You'd do something like this in your template:

```
{exp:allow_eecode}
  {your_custom_field}
{/exp:allow_eecode}
```

If your custom field has `{title}` in it, it should be processed.

Of course, you need to be careful with this because they could potentially enter any EE code.