# Use variable in content

Tags: variable

Is it possible to use a variable in my content?  If got my basic pages with a title and body. In the CP I use a WYSIWYG editor for the body. 
For example. Now I don't want to put my name or phonenumber on every page. Or I want to put a Username somewhere in the content. Like you do with Emailings. 
Could I use something like {username} or {phonenumber} in my editor?

Thx, 
Martijn

Comment: See: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10333/using-the-entry-title-variable-in-an-channel-entry-field/10335#10335

Comment: you should see these add-ons http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/allow-ee-code and http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/allow-more-ee-code I think, "Allow More EE Code" would be better.

Comment: In general I'd recommend trying to be more structured with your content vs. just having big old catch-all WYSIWYG fields for page content. Doing so will help you avoid needing to use variables in content, make your content reusable, and just in general play to EE's strengths rather than make it a different sort of Dreamweaver.